# How to configure Stylesheet for QWizard

Tags: qt

I have not been able to find an answer to how I configure the BannerPixmap for QWizard using a stylesheet or Qt Designer.  Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: What do you mean with "configure"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is your wizard using the [ModernStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#WizardStyle-enum) WizardStyle?  It looks like it won't appear otherwise.

Comment: I can't find what the property value is to add it to the style sheet.  If I use a style sheet, then it seems I am unable to add the bannerpixmap via code as described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Pixmap property, either on the wizard or on the wizard page; for instance this:

```
    self.setPixmap(QtGui.QWizard.WatermarkPixmap, QtGui.QPixmap(":/plugins/eaf/eaf3.jpg"))
```

(where the pixmap is some Qt resource)

The first parameter of this method is the wizard role. As pointed out on the comment above, the roles in use depend on the wizard style:

- WatermarkPixmap (used by ClassicStyle and ModernStyle)
- BannerPixmap (used by ModernStyle)
- LogoPixmap (used by ClassicStyle and ModernStyle)
- BackgroundPixmap (used by MacStyle)

You can set the wizard style explicitly, with:

```
setWizardStyle ( WizardStyle style )
```

[1] https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#wizard-look-and-feel

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the button in a wizard looking at the QWizard source code to get the objet name.

Each button have it's own object name.
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qwizard.cpp.html#_ZL22object_name_for_buttonN7QWizard12WizardButtonE

```
static QString object_name_for_button(QWizard::WizardButton which)
{
    switch (which) {
    case QWizard::CommitButton:
        return QLatin1String("qt_wizard_") + QLatin1String("commit");
    case QWizard::FinishButton:
        return QLatin1String("qt_wizard_") + QLatin1String("finish");
    case QWizard::CancelButton:
        return QLatin1String("qt_wizard_") + QLatin1String("cancel");
    case QWizard::BackButton:
    case QWizard::NextButton:
    case QWizard::HelpButton:
    case QWizard::CustomButton1:
    case QWizard::CustomButton2:
    case QWizard::CustomButton3:
        // Make navigation buttons detectable as passive interactor in designer
        return QLatin1String("__qt__passive_wizardbutton") + QString::number(which);
    case QWizard::Stretch:
    case QWizard::NoButton:
    //case QWizard::NStandardButtons:
    //case QWizard::NButtons:
        ;
    }
    Q_UNREACHABLE();
    return QString();
}
```

In the style sheet:

```
/*Next button in the wizard */
QPushButton#__qt__passive_wizardbutton1
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(35, 200, 183, 100%), stop:1 rgba(35, 167, 212, 100%));
    color: white;
    font: bold;
}

QPushButton#qt_wizard_finish
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(35, 200, 183, 100%), stop:1 rgba(35, 167, 212, 100%));
    color: white;
    font: bold;
}

QPushButton#qt_wizard_commit
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(35, 200, 183, 100%), stop:1 rgba(35, 167, 212, 100%));
    color: white;
    font: bold;
}
```